# Cannot perform fit_transform on the categorical data

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am getting the following error while encoding the categorical data using a Column Transformer. When I am trying to fit the data using fit_transform it says index tuple out of range. The column which I am trying encode is of string datatype.

```
#First encoding the x features
#we need encoder class and column transformer class
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
#create objects of above classes
ct = ColumnTransformer(transformers=[('encoder',OneHotEncoder(),[0])],remainder='passthrough')
# fit the object on dataset and transform it
x = np.array(ct.fit_transform(x)) #line creating errror
```

The error information is as follows:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-37-d7c6138a2cdf> in <module>
      7 ct = ColumnTransformer(transformers=[('encoder',OneHotEncoder(),[0])],remainder='passthrough')
      8 # fit the object on dataset and transform it
----> 9 x = np.array(ct.fit_transform(x))

c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\sklearn\compose\_column_transformer.py in fit_transform(self, X, y)
    514         self._validate_transformers()
    515         self._validate_column_callables(X)
--> 516         self._validate_remainder(X)
    517 
    518         result = self._fit_transform(X, y, _fit_transform_one)

c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\sklearn\compose\_column_transformer.py in _validate_remainder(self, X)
    319             self._df_columns = X.columns
    320 
--> 321         self._n_features = X.shape[1]
    322         cols = []
    323         for columns in self._columns:

IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

Comment: I think .fit_transform() is already returning a numpy array.